# HF arc starter and full bridge IGBT driver protection

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, high-voltage, high-frequency

Had developed HF arc starter scheme [image: hf arc starter] and it worked fine until I accidentally pressed arc start **push button** when circuit was shorted (torch stick on work peace). After that all 4 IGBTs in my inverter blow up. Inverter uses full bridge output scheme built on FGH60N60 IGBTs.

Both L1 and T2 are massive (150mm in diameter) ferrite thoroids. 
HF arc module is [like this](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/New-DC-3V-6V-bis-400kV-400000V-Boost-Step-up-Power-Module-High-Voltage-Generator/32755768779.html)

I think damage was due L1 saturation (short circuit), so it loosed reactive resistance vastly and high voltage leak to inverter, is this correct?, any suggestions?

Components was chosen based on availability..
Sorry for bad English

Comment: Sure the L1 didn't make its job if it was saturated. Also the RV2, C, D3 and D4 make no sense since they sink the HV signal.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič >> Also the RV2, C, D3 and D4 make no sense since they sink the HV signal - why? they are intended to bypass HV from inverter. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: If LL would work, then the C is bypassing the HF signal and LL is blocking it. RV2, D3,D4 would probably sink some overvoltage, but as you learned they didn't.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank you, it's clear now. Where should I look for solution then?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's so little power from those HV modules that I don't believe there could be enough current to saturate large inductors ... I would be looking for paths that allowed overvoltage (ESD) to reach the IGBTs somehow, probably common mode paths given all those RVs and diodes. And surely you don't need "400000V" to start the arc - I'd be looking for something limited to a few kv at most, that would be much easier to keep in the right place.

Comment: @BrianDrummond indeed, this HV module can't saturate L1 itself, but there was sort circuit (about 70A) when I pressed button, so saturation is more likely occurred. 2. I checked parts but only with multimeter - seems I need more detailed checking. >> And surely you don't need "400000V" to start the arc - I'd be looking for something limited to a few kv at most, that would be much easier to keep in the right place. - agree, thought voltage can be relatively easily adjusted with spark gap

Comment: Still... it looks as if all your voltage protection is differential, and you said it's a full bridge. So that keeps both ends of the bridge within 100V of each other ... but potentially thousands of volts away from ground. What protects the IGBTs against common mode on Inverter- and Inverter+?

Comment: @BrianDrummond yeah, that's true - I have idea how to fix this.

Comment: @dimethyl, were you able to build a fixed circuit? Can you please share the details, schematics etc. I am also facing a similar issue, will be great it you can help.